# Use a property value for $id in Json.NET

Tags: json.net

I have two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Person person &&
                this.Id.Equals(person.Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(this.Id);
    }
}

[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Organization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(IsReference = true)]
    public IList<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();

    public PrinterSettings PrinterSettings { get; set; }
    public PageSettings PageSettings { get; set; }
}
```

And serializer settings:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
```

When this is serialized with Json.NET, an `$id` property is created for each element. Is it possible to use the `public Guid Id { get; set; }` property for this `$id` value?